# Operations on the controls within the repeater control

Tags: orbeon

A form in a Orbeon form builder contains a repeater control(new repeat).Suppose there are three text controls on each row(or repeat) of a repeater control(new repeat).first two text controls on each row contains numeric values.I want to bring the product of first two text controls to the third text control at run time without any event.there will be multiple numbers of repeat in the runtime ,i.e the row may increase but for each the calculation much reflect at runtime and for each row product of first two must be viewed on the third one

Answer (score 0):

1. Name the fields in the first and second column (click on cog wheel to the right of the field). Say you picked the names `quantity` and `price`.
2. For the 3rd field, enter the following XPath expression in *calculated value*, all in one line (in the *Edit Validation Properties* you get by clicking on the red exclamation mark):

   ```
   if ($quantity castable as xs:double and $price castable as xs:double)
   then $quantity * $price
   else 'n/a'
   ```

You refer to other controls by name, preceding the name by a dollar sign, and here we check that a value is indeed a number with `$gaga castable as xs:double`.

Comment: Its ok with this xpath expression when there is only one row in the repeater control.But on adding new rows ,i.e on increasing the repeat at run time, all results in the controls of third column changes to the else value( "n/a"). This is working only for a single row of a repeater control(new repeat).Because for every repeat the value must be calculated for each row separately.